# Entity Framework 5 entity in separate dll

Tags: dll, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, shared-libraries

I have a DLL that is a logging component that we use in many different projects. This logging component is designed to be entirely self-contained, and thus it must have its database connection string internal to it. In this project, it is completely unacceptable to require that its connection string be copied to the app.config of any project that uses it.

This has been working great for years, but now we have found that mixing its older ADO tech with new apps that use EF results in horrible performance when the logging is being done. For example, adding a single log entry when the application starts results in a > 30 second delay before the app opens.

So to combat this, I have re-written this component to use EF.

The problem is under the current EF (version 4.4 since we are targeting .Net Framework 4.0) does not offer a constructor to DBContext that allows you to specify the entire connection string. The code attempts to change the Database.Connection.ConnectionString, but the DBContext object insists on looking in the App.Config for the connection string even though we are giving it a new one.

I must get around this behavior.

Comment: unfortunately I don't believe there is one.  However, there is nothing stopping you from writing your own config section to get this information, then setting your own connection string.  Not optimal, but you have to pay a price for magic.

Comment: You can pass the connection to the context's constructor.

Comment: OK, I have this worked out now.

I created a partial class to extend the entity class that was generated by the EF. I put a constructor with a string argument, which passed that argument to the DbContext constructor. And I used the EntityConnectionStringBuilder to construct the connection string to my model/database.

This actually is ideal for this component, so that each application that uses it does not have to be concerned with where the logging is taking place. And we specify a DNS alias to our logging database, so we can move it from server to server if necessary.

Comment: Chris can you post an example.  This is a popular question with no good examples